# Spring boot actuator interferes with the HTTPS requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am working with `spring-boot-starter-actuator` for adding a health check endpoint to my service.
The issue, which I am dealing with, is when I add actuator dependency, my service stops receiving requests. However, when I remove the actuator dependency, my service works as expected.

**How could I fix this issue?**

1. This is the error showing by swagger when I try the service out:
   [image]
2. This is the error showing by postman:
   [image]
3. This is the actuator dependency tree:

```
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.28:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.12.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
```

4. This is my actuator dependency:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

***Note:*** Spring security is not part of the project and my spring boot version is 2.5.10

Comment: Where is your application deployed?

Comment: k8s and routing with route 53

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this config:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedMethods("*")
                    .allowedOrigins("*");
    }

}
```